# Troubleshooting "There is no extension able to load the configuration for 'knp_menu'"

Tags: symfony, invalidargumentexception

I am running Symfony 2.0.6, and I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the
>   configuration for "knp_menu" (in
>   /home/www/Symfony/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace
>   "knp_menu"

It works in DEV, but not in PROD enviroment.

Comment: Have you cleared your PROD cache?

Comment: yes, i deleted all cache folders

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message means that you got an entry "knp_menu" in your config.yml which is not used by any extension.

It's either a caching problem (you introduced the extension, e.g. a bundle, and then not cleared the prod cache), or you load a specific bundle only within the dev environment (as the profiler in a default symfony2 app).

Try clearing the cache using `php app/console clear:cache --env=prod --no-debug`. If the problem exists anyhow, find out which bundle uses knp_menu and either delete the configuration or enable the bundle.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works.don't see there where bundles active only for 'dev' and 'test'